# Efficient findall() processing?

Tags: prolog, clause, prolog-findall

I have the following structure of "facts".

```
if( conds, score, idx).
```

Then I expect to have thousands of them. The 'conds' is a conditions that will be evaluated as the facts are processed. For every fact that is true I store the score and the index in a list for further processing. 
The general idea is to `findall/3` facts and then go over them ...

```
findall([Cond, Q, Ix], clause(if(Cond, Q, Ix), true), Conds)
check(Conds, True_QIxLst) ...
```

My worry is that `findall/3` would gobble all thousand of facts for every run i.e. use too much memory.

How would I do what `findall` does, but process the conditions one-by-one. 
I will still process all the conditions, but I would like to use less memory.

---

As per "mat" suggestion this seem to work out :

```
is_true(Q,Ix) :-
   if(Cond, Q, Ix),
   check(Cond).

run(QI) :-
   findall([Q,Ix], is_true(Q,Ix), QI).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to writing efficient Prolog code is to delegate as much work as possible to the *engine*.

Everything you do explicitly (i.e., within Prolog) will typically be *slower* than if the same thing is accomplished by the core engine *implicitly*. If that isn't the case, it means that there is an opportunity for improvement in the core engine.

In your particular case, if `findall/3` would use too much memory, consider whether `findall/3` is even necessary for your use case.

How about getting out of the way, and delegating it all to Prolog's built-in backtracking?

```
true_q_ix(Q, Ix) :-
    if(Cond, Q, Ix),
    cond_is_true(Cond).
```

No `findall/3`, no nothing: Just plain backtracking, yielding all `Q` and `Ix` for which `Cond` evaluates to true in your interpretation.

[**Don't do anything! Nothing!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKIpCPS-oZc)

If necessary, you can still wrap this in `findall/3`, paying its various costs.

Comment: how would i collect Q's and Ix's ? i tried with separate rule calling this one, but search always start from the first "if"

Comment: You can collect `Q` and `Ix` for example with `findall/3`: `findall(Q-Ix, true_q_ix(Q, Ix), QIxs)`. This is now limited to all those `Q` and `Ix` where the conditions are actually true.

Comment: Great! Still, the question somehow remains: Do you really need to collect all solutions? Why? In Prolog, you normally state what holds about a solution, and on backtracking, you get solutions that satisfy these conditions.

Comment: ooo, i need to pick the best Ix based on the Score, so I can execute corresponding actions.

Comment: OK, I see! It is possible to do this with less space. However, collecting all solutions and picking a minimal one is one way to do it too.